# Manage large number of domain names

Tags: domain-name, domain

There are a couple of posts here about keeping on top of registering domain names, we use recurring billing so that sorts that out, rather have a domain renewed that I didnt want than the other way round!

My question is about managing the DNS profile for domains. We are approaching 100 domain names that we now look after, a large chunk of which are for the same shared application, spread over a couple of servers.

Is there a way to mass edit the DNS records for these domains or do I have to go through the web administration for the registra (123-reg in this case as thats who we started with and the inertia to moving is large).

We are moving to some new IPs, and mail server SPFs need updating sometimes so its all a bit of a nightmare to do via the web pages domain by domain.

Thanks

Comment: Do you control the DNS Server Directly? Is it a Microsoft DNS Server or other?

Comment: No these are domains registered with 123-ref and all dba records are controlled by them.

I know its unlikely but I wondered if there was a way to 'send' batch domain updates.

Thanks

Comment: I found the inertia large until they made a change that screwed me. I left within a week.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have to use the registrar's DNS.

Yes, you can mass-edit zones, however depending on your registrar, you might actually have to stop using their DNS to do so.

The bad news is that, depending on your registrar, it might be a PITA initially to change all the domains to use your own self-hosted nameservers.

Should you choose to self-host your DNS, and if you are using BIND or NSD, you can put anything that is going to be the same in its own file, and then include that file in your zone files. You can even have one zone file used by multiple domains. For instance:

```
; Zone template A - db.template.a
$TTL    7200
$INCLUDE db.soa
$INCLUDE db.ns
$INCLUDE db.mx
$INCLUDE db.www
; put whatever else here
```

..

```
; db.soa
@       IN SOA ns1.example.com. hostmaster.example.com. (
                            2014073001      ; Serial
                                  2160      ; Refresh
                                  3600      ; Retry
                                604800      ; Expire
                                  7200 )    ; Negative TTL
```

..

```
; db.ns
@       IN NS ns1.example.com.
@       IN NS ns2.example.com.
```

...

```
; db.mx
@       IN MX 10 mx10.example.com.
@       IN MX 20 mx20.example.com.
@       IN TXT "v=spf1 a mx -all"
```

...

```
; db.www
@       IN A 192.0.2.1
www     IN A 192.0.2.1
www     IN MX 0 .
```

If you are going to self host and use PowerDNS, you could even use a database instead of actual zone files, and make mass changes with an SQL query.